# Real Analysis Proof with absolute values

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The question is consider the polynomial 
$P(X) = X^d + a_{d−1}X^{d−1} + · · · + a_1 X + a_0$,
where $d \geq 1$ and $a_0$, . . . , $a_{d−1}$ are real numbers. 
Define the number
$M := 1 + |a_{d−1}| + · · · + |a_1| + |a_0|$.
Prove the following:

(1) For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x| \geq M$,
$$
\left| \frac{a_{d−1}}{x} + \frac{a_{d−2}}{x^2} + · · · + \frac{a_{1}}{x^{d-1}}+\frac{a_{0}}{x^d} \right| <1.
$$
(2) For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x| \geq M$, 
$P(x)= x^d (1 + e)$ for some $e \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|e| < 1$.

(3) For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x| \geq M$, $P(x)$ is not equal to $0$.

I honestly do not know where to start, I tried to manipulate the absolute values in the equation but can't seem to get anywhere, and I think its because I don't really know the point of this proof or what it is exactly I am proving. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: your $P(X)$ is not a polynomial. should the slashes there be removed?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can major the expression substituting x with M (x^2>x, ... , x^d>x so you can get rid of the exponents)  which will give something smaller than 1 because M > a_0+...+a_(d-1).

For the second part just put x^d in evidence in the formulation of P(x). You'll get x^d(1 + (...)). Because you've proven a) already the result is true.

As for the third part, notice that P(x)=0 only if x=0 or e=1 (using 2)). Both are Impossible from M>1 and e<1

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused, what do you mean by major the expression substituting x with M?

Comment: First you can say that the sum you have in module is smaller than having all the Xs with exponents 1 (if X>M then X<X^2<...). Then substitute all the Xs with M, which will give you a new expression bigger than the last and smaller than 1.